# Angular 2+ ReactiveForms with select control

Tags: html, angular, typescript, reactive

I'm implementing the reactiveforms in my first angular project, I can not figure out why the value of the select is not being changed. For the input field of normal text it works quietly, for the field of select nothing happens. I followed several tutorials and could not solve. The form loads perfectly and has no errors on the console.

my-component.html:

```
<dynamic-form [config]="config" #form="dynamic-Form" (submit)="realizarLogin(form)">
    </dynamic-form>
    {{ form.valid }} {{ form.value | json }}
```

form-select.component.html:

```
<div class="dynamic-field form-select" [formGroup]="group">
  <label>{{ config.label }}</label>
  <select [formControlName]="config.name">
        <option value="">{{ config.placeholder }}</option>
        <option *ngFor="let option of config.options">
          {{ option }}
        </option>
      </select>
</div>
```

dynamic-form.component.html:

```
<form class="dynamic-form" [formGroup]="form">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let field of config;" dynamicField [config]="field" [group]="form">
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

dynamic-form.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    DynamicFieldDirective,
    DynamicFormComponent,
    FormButtonComponent,
    FormInputComponent,
    FormSelectComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    DynamicFormComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    FormButtonComponent,
    FormInputComponent,
    FormSelectComponent
  ]
```

login.component.ts:

```
export class LoginComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(DynamicFormComponent) form: DynamicFormComponent;

  config: FieldConfig[] = [
    {
      type: 'input',
      label: 'Full name',
      name: 'name',
      placeholder: 'Enter your name',
      validation: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]
    },
    {
      type: 'select',
      label: 'Favourite Food',
      name: 'food',
      options: ['Pizza', 'Hot Dogs', 'Knakworstje', 'Coffee'],
      placeholder: 'Select an option',
      validation: [Validators.required]
    },
    {
      label: 'Submit',
      name: 'submit',
      type: 'button',
    }
  ];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let previousValid = this.form.valid;
    this.form.changes.subscribe(() => {
      if (this.form.valid !== previousValid) {
        previousValid = this.form.valid;
        this.form.setDisabled('submit', !previousValid);
      }
    });

    this.form.setDisabled('submit', true);
    this.form.setValue('name', 'Todd Motto');
  }

  submit(value: {[name: string]: any}) {
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

login.module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LoginRoutingModule,
    DynamicFormModule
  ],
  declarations: [LoginComponent]
})
export class LoginModule {}
```

app module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,

    RetaguardaModule,
    LoginModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    LoginGuard,
    LoginService,
    Ambiente
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*I changed the code by showing the structure in which I want to load the code. The problem is that in the login module does not open. It's the only difference from the example I put in the question footer*

Remembering that for the "name" property of the array "binding" is working. The code should work according to the following example:
https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-forms/

> I noticed that in the example code what is printed on the console, it
>   is an "object", in my case it is a DynamicFormComponent.

Comment: Would you like to create a plunker?

Comment: I do not know how to do.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/UPPNUJr2SyMqOXUHBgLl?p=preview

Comment: Your code is working, but I can not find the problem in my code @yurzui

Comment: @yurzui I changed the code by showing the structure in which I want to load the code.

Comment: I noticed in your code that when logging to the console, what is printed in the log in your case, is an "object", in my case it is a DynamicFormComponent

Comment: Do you have github repo to reproduce it?

Comment: @yurzui No, but I believe that being able to map why your console exit is different from mine on the console, we will find the problem.

Comment: @yurzui If I set the value this way: "this.form.setValue ('food', 'Pizza');" Directly on my component json on the screen updates normally, however the reverse process still does not work.I've also identified that your generated html is just select, my generate a <ul> with the <li> tags inside for each select option, this happens over the <select>

Comment: Change my plunker with your version code and say if it can be reproduced

Comment: @yurzui I do not know if the structure was clear, but I could not make the html layout appear. If you find the problem you can enter as an answer.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Gw1C3G9K2A4Zm3GrUUxc?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved when removing the class from Materialize, after resover the problem went after other people who had the same problem, follow the link of a possible solution:

Or just apply the class

```
<select [formControlName]="config.name" class="browser-default">
```

in the  input tag.